# Necron Monolith movement speed

Tags: warhammer-40k

Necron codex says that Monolith is a skimmer that can move up to 6". Then it can fire it's weapons.

Does that mean that instead of firing I can move it to another 6" like with any other vehicle or am I allowed to only move it 6" a turn?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Monolith is a verrrrrrrrrry slow skimmer -- it can only move 6" per turn, but it can also ignore terrain features while moving.

I don't have the Codex handy, but I'm fairly certain the Monolith says it can *only* ever move 6" per turn.

Comment: This is correct. The ponderous rule takes precedence over the skimmer rule.